# How do I order subpages within my static ones in Wordpress.org 2.8.4?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I already applied a custom order for the toplevel navigation of my page, but it doesn't automatically sort the submenus alphabetically, although i assumed this behavior:

```
Pages are usually ordered alphabetically, but you can put a number above to change the order pages appear in. (We know this is a little janky, it’ll be better in future releases.)
```

I implemented the navigation using this line of code:

```
<?php wp_page_menu( 'sort_column=menu_order' ); ?>
```

Finally, do I really have to go and manually order my static pages, or should i manually program the order of the menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the [My Page Order extension](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-page-order/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: many thx for your suggestion, this tool makes sorting pages a better experience. The wordpress developer team really have to make up an integrated solution for this though.

Comment: In what you posted, it does say "We know this is a little janky, it’ll be better in future releases." Hopefully, something like this will eventually be built into WordPress, but until then, this is the best way to manage what you want, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yeah right, but is there any sulution for making submenus order alphabetically without having to use such a tool? I know it works kinda, but i think computers can do this type of work way better than me :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, have you tried:

```
wp_page_menu('sort_column=post_title');
```

instead of 'menu_order'?

Per the Codex, it looks like the title would result in alphabetical sorting?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_page_menu

Comment: I tried this out already, but i lose the custom order of the toplevel navigation this way.